# How do deployed .NET programs reference assemblies in GAC?

Tags: .net, gac, .net-assembly

Best practice for developing .NET programs seems to be this: never reference dlls from GAC while developing.

However, How should I get the actual deployed product to reference the dlls in the GAC? For example, if my product is a very simple windows app, then how should I program my code so that the single deployed .exe file references `System.Windows.Forms.dll` from GAC?

I am new to .NET development, so I might be missing some very basics.

Comment: "Best practice for developing .NET programs seems to be this: never reference dlls from GAC while developing." [Citation needed] I don't like adding my own assemblies to GAC, but I never heard anything against referencing system assemblies from the GAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the references from the list in the `Add References` dialog. This adds entries to your `.csproj` that look like the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="System" />
  <Reference Include="System.Core" />
  <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
  <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
  <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  <Reference Include="System.Data" />
  <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

You don't ship these dlls with your project. You could ship the redist setup of the .net framework, but that's only a good idea if you ship physical copies of your program, not if you offer a download. Including them with your program is probably a copyright violation. And of course on Mono, future windows/.net versions etc a different `System.Windows.Forms` assembly needs to be used, that wouldn't work if you distributed your own copy of this file.

These assemblies will get loaded from the GAC. But that's fine since they are part of the .net framework after all. The compiled references will look similar to `mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089`. This way the framework will choose the correct version and will make sure that the references assemblies are from the correct creator.

The guideline of not using the GAC refers to your own or third party assemblies. You ship those with your application and just have them in the same directory as your main program. Adding them to the GAC is only needed in a few specific scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is not to reference `System.Windows.Forms.dll` from the GAC. Include that DLL in your application instead.

**UPDATE**

If you wish to add references to dlls in the GAC you can do so using the usual Add References Dialog.

Browsing to `C:\Windows\assembly` is where you can select those references.

Comment: Why? That file is bound to be on the system.

Comment: How does that answer the question? I want to know how programs reference dlls in the GAC, and it seems like you're saying "pretend like the GAC is not there and never use it". What am I missing?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a bit more information on how to actually reference dlls in the GAC. I didn't mean to suggest that you should never reference items in the GAC, I think I just slightly misunderstood your question.

Comment: err what? Why the hell would he include a system dll in his application?

Comment: @CodeInChaos, any program which creates Window forms for the user _has_ to have access to System.Windows.Forms.dll at runtime, correct? I really am new to .NET, so where else would the program get access to that dll during runtime? Would I ship System.Windows.Forms.dll with my app?

Comment: Since windows forms is part of the .net framework you use the version that's already installed. You don't ship the dll with your program directly. You probably don't even have the rights to do that.